# Graphic User Interfaces for a Database

Tags: python, database, user-interface

I'm trying to learn how to create a database for the school storage and a friend told me that it can be done with Python. Is that true ? If not, where can I learn about programming databases besides MySQL ?.

Also how can I create a friendly GUI to help the user with the database?

Comment: Where does a GUI come into your question?

Comment: This question is of poor quality

Comment: @pynator poor quality = just learning thank you for your patiente
@ Matt Ball oh yeah i forgot about that while I was writting the question thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to find a Python driver/connector for the database of your choice.

A database (or more specifically Relational Database Management System, RDBMS) is a piece of software that is specially designed to handle data.  Python, in and of itself, is not sufficient in this regard; you still need a database like MySql.

But you can connect to MySql from python using a connector or driver.  The connectors that are available for MySQL are here: http://www.mysql.com/products/connector/

Answer (score 0):

I have personnaly already use SQL database with python. I use sqlalchemy.

https://www.sqlalchemy.org

There is a really good official documentation

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/tutorial.html